# One-to-one user messaging database schema

Tags: laravel, database-design, chat, database-schema

How to implement database schema for private one-to-one user messaging using Laravel? All threads are only one-to-one, so no group messages or multiple participants. Best example is a dating site where each message thread for user is represented by the recipient.

I did the simplest one table approach:

```
id,sender_id,recipient_id,body
```

This works. The problem is a user can't delete conversation while other user keeps the messages.

Another approach is three tables: `messages`, `threads` and `participants`. This is the same as with multiple participants, simply limiting to only two. Then, if a user deletes a thread I can simply remove him from participants for this thread.

A problem with this approach: User A sends a message to user B. Then user A deletes the thread (removed from thread participants). User B gets to keep the messages (he's a participant). What if now user A sends again a message to user B? This will create a new thread since old thread is lost for this user. But the message needs to go to the old thread, since there's always only one thread between two users.

What database schema would you suggest for only one to one messaging between users, while allowing thread deletion?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to leave the single table approach, and consider the deletion of a thread by a user as an operation that, instead of actually removing data, *hide* the messages to that user in the application from this moment on.

This could be implemented by modifying your table in this way:

```
id, sender_id, recipient_id, hidden_to_sender, hiddent_to_recipient, body
```

so that, when a user removes a thread, all its messages are marked as hidden to him (and *only* to him). When he send a new message to other person, it is simply added the the previous thread, with hidden set to false for both partecipant.

You could also consider an optimization such that, when a user remove a conversation with another user, if all the messages are marked as hidden to the other user, you can erase them, instead of marking the messages as hidden also to the first user.